# Creating nested arrays of set structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects with named keys as follows:

```
Array1 [
  {
    'town1': 'London', // string
    'town2': 'Paris', // string
    'distance': 123456, // number
  },
  {
    'town1': 'Seoul', // string
    'town2': 'Tokio', // string
    'distance': 654321, // number
  },
  {},{},... // Objects with same properties
]
```

Note that there might be objects without these keys. They should be skipped.
Having all this I want to create a new **Array of arrays with 2 objects inside** with the following rigid structure:

```
Array2 [
  [{ name: 'town1', value: 'distance'}, { name: 'town2'}],
  [{ name: 'town1', value: 'distance'}, { name: 'town2'}],
  [{...}, {...}],   // All other objects with existing town1-town2-distance
]
```

How one could achieve it in the most efficient and fast way?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thank you for your question! I know how to create a simple object { name: 'town1', value: 'distance' } by reducing or mapping forEach(a => {}). But I can't figure out how to iterate 2 objects inside array inside another array...

Comment: Isn't the output supposed to be `[{ name: 'London', value: 123456 }, { name: 'Paris' }]`?

Comment: Yep! And these values would vary depending on objects inside Array1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I want to have my try as well! Why did nobody think about reduce? It's faster than for-loop! And more elegant. IMO at least.

So I've done few tests, and here are results:

[image]

And heres the code:

1) `Array.prototype.reduce()` with `Array.prototype.push()`

```
const array2 = array1.reduce((arr, obj) => {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty('town1') && obj.hasOwnProperty('town2') && obj.hasOwnProperty('value')) {
    arr.push([ { name: obj.town1, value: obj.distance }, { name: obj.town2 } ])
  }

  return arr
}, [])
```

2) `Array.prototype.reduce()` with `Array.prototype.concat()`

```
const array2 = array1.reduce((arr, obj) => (
  (obj.hasOwnProperty('town1') && obj.hasOwnProperty('town2') && obj.hasOwnProperty('value'))
    ? Array.prototype.concat(arr, [[ { name: obj.town1, value: obj.distance }, { name: obj.town2 } ]])
    : arr
  ), [])
```

3) `Array.prototype.reduce()` with spread operator

```
array2 = array1.reduce((arr, obj) => (
  (obj.hasOwnProperty('town1') && obj.hasOwnProperty('town2') && obj.hasOwnProperty('value'))
    ?  [...arr, [ { name: obj.town1, value: obj.distance }, { name: obj.town2 } ]]
    : arr
  ), [])
```

4) And @Emueeus go. `For-loop` with `Array.prototype.push()`

```
for (let i = 0; i<array1.length; i++) {
  if (array1[i].hasOwnProperty('town1') && array1[i].hasOwnProperty('town2') && array1[i].hasOwnProperty('distance')) {
    array2.push([{name:array1[i]['town1'], value: array1[i]['distance']}, { name: array1[i]['town2']}])
  }
}
```

Here's the test:
http://jsfiddle.net/4bca0g2u/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Now that's confusing! I'm constantly getting various results using jsperf.com on your 4 tests. Looks like these tests are conducted on my machine, which is not very trustworthy, so there should be kind of remote-like services. If you know any online script measuring tools like Pingdom or Google Speed for websites, please share!

Comment: Here it is: https://jsperf.com/reduces-vs-for-loop. What do you use for testing performance?

Comment: @Igniter I wrote a quick performance test. Iterated each of those solutions 100k times, measured their performance with `performance.now()` and divided the result by the iteration count. I've fired it on my local machine, you might be right, testing it on multiple environments would give a more trustworthy result. Here's the test through http://jsfiddle.net/4bca0g2u/

Comment: I agree because you did one iteration, I'm not agree that it is more elegant. :)

Comment: @Emeeus oh, you have every right to do so :) Although native functions seem to be more readable than for-loop. At least to me

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a single `map` would work for you.

```
let mustHave = ['town1', 'town2', 'distance'];
Array1.filter(obj => mustHave.every(key => obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
      .map(obj => [{ name : obj.town1, value: obj.distance}, { name : obj.town2 }])
```

Edit: Didn't see that you didn't want to map objects without those keys. The filter takes care of that.

Comment: it would, but would throw undefined if any of those keys would be missing. OP wants those objects to be skipped

Comment: @PatrykCieszkowski didn't see it, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

MinusFour's solution is almost correct. You'd also want to filter the elements which actually have the keys required:

```js
Array2.filter(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty("town1") &&
                     obj.hasOwnProperty("town2") &&
                     obj.hasOwnProperty("distance"))
      .map(obj => [{ name: obj.town1, value: obj.distance }, { name: obj.town2 }]);
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Just one iteration ( O(n) ) using `for`. It's faster than filter and map (2 iterations) see this https://jsperf.com/mapfiltervsfor/1

```js
var array1 = [
    {
      'town1': 'London', // string
      'town2': 'Paris', // string
      'distance': 123456, // number
    },
    {
      'town1': 'Seoul', // string
      'town2': 'Tokio', // string
      'distance': 654321, // number
    }
  ];

  var array2 = [];

  for(let i = 0; i<array1.length; i++){

     if(array1[i].hasOwnProperty('town1') &&  array1[i].hasOwnProperty('town2') && array1[i].hasOwnProperty('distance')){
        array2.push([{name:array1[i]['town1'], value: array1[i]['distance']}, { name: array1[i]['town2']}])
     }

  }
  console.log(array2)
```

Comment: First, interesting! That was unexpected I should say. Thank you for separate concerns about performance and the link to that site I didn't know about! I prefer this approach!

Comment: @Igniter Thanks, as a general rule (maybe not always), native methods like `.map` `.sort`, `.filter`.. etc. are faster than plain `for` but sometimes those methods doesn't resolve the whole issue, and we have to use them more than once, in those cases is preferably in my opinion, to use `for` if we can resolve the issue with less iterations .